# --begin(container) - is defined behavier?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am implementing decrement operator for my custom bidirectional iterator.  Is decrementing iterator pointing at 1st element of Range is defined behavior? Does it have some special value after decrementing,  like  Range.end()?

Comment: Em.. so what must mean --begin(iter) ?

Comment: Just remember: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterator requirements are rather clear: In 24.2.6 [bidirectional.iterators], Table 110:

> `--r` (Expression) `X&` (Return type) pre: there exists `s` such that `r == ++s`.

Since there is no such `s` for `c.begin()`, it can't be decremented without violating the precondition.

Answer (score 8):

In the iterators of all of the standard library containers, that is undefined behavior.  But if you are making your own iterator class, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: The standard library almost has an example of this: `std::forward_list` has a before-begin iterator, but it's not reachable by decrementing the begin()

Comment: Ah, that is why you said _almost_, :). I did not know it is _unreachable_. Thanks for the info.